# How to access Windows system reserved with Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

My Windows 7 got corrupted, and when starting the PC, it says that `bootmgr` is missing. Since I don't have the Windows disc, I'm trying to put this file using Ubuntu, but I can't access the system reserved partition, the error I'm getting is:

```
unable to access system reserved  
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/reserved
```

I can't use windows 7 anymore due to that error. The thing is, I don't have any installation disc or bootable USB, not even any license. I was trying to just copy that missing file into "system reserved" using an Ubuntu bootable USB, but I can't access that partition. The error I get when trying to enter is the following:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ubuntu/Reservado para el sistema: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sda1" "/media/ubuntu/Reservado para el sistema"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x48cd8b49  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 27785  usa_count: 10275: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x1bf41ffff) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

The closest I got to access it was using “Disks” and changing mount options. With this method, it did let me enter the partition, but it showed nothing on it and it obviously didn't let me paste the bootmgr file.

The other method I tried was nautilus, but nautilus doesn’'t even show that partition.

I really don't want to buy a Windows 7 installation DVD or a bootable USB (I really don't know how to make them and I don't have the money to afford multiple USBs for trial and error).

Comment: Think your best bet would be to use a win 7 install disk.  Can download from Microsoft if you still have the license from here.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7.  Might need to use 'WoeUSB' to burn usb from ubuntu, for a bootable usb.